# why is get error with getBuffer()?

Tags: java, xml

Hy i have error message with these code:

```
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
Writer outWriter = new StringWriter();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult( outWriter );
t.transform(source, result);
StringBuffer sb = outWriter .getBuffer();     //with this line,complet error message down
return sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;

    }

**down: "StringBuffer sb = outWriter .getBuffer(); 
  symbol:   method getBuffer()
  location: variable outWriter of type Writer
```

Note: C:\Users\Desktop\BikeShop FINALE\src\bikeshop\orej.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    1 error"**

Somebody know why?

Answer (score 1):

The method `getBuffer` is undefined for `java.io.Writer`. Declare as `StringWriter`:

```
StringWriter outWriter = new StringWriter();
```

Comment: but when i put this line I must to delete this line: "Writer outWriter = new StringWriter();"       there is my project,I want to with Employee and orej   class to write to xml the data.but is nothing to write...   https://www.dropbox.com/sh/x057q8rnw27kl24/GPbdbymsw7

Comment: can be problem when i have on the end  return null ?                      .... t.transform(source, result);

StringBuffer sb = outWriter .getBuffer(); 

return sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;

    }

Comment: Fixing that problem has revealed another. Ensure your try/catch is well formed and your `return` statements are "balanced".